# Backbone.js PushStates: Fallback for Internet Explorer not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, pushstate

My site has just implemented pushstates in Backbone.js and the entire site breaks for IE. How should I create a fallback for IE?

**What I am trying to achieve**

Main URL: `http://mydomain.com/explore`

Another URL: `'http://mydomain.com/explore/1234`

The main page of the site is `http://mydomain.com/explore` which triggers the router function `explore`.

When a user visits `http://mydomain.com/explore/1234`, Backbone's router will trigger the function `viewListing`, which is the same as function `explore`, but also includes details for item id `1234`.

**Backbone.js Router**

```
// Router
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'explore': 'explore',
        'explore/:id': 'viewListing',
    },

    explore: function() {
        this.listingList    = new ListingCollection();
        // More code here
    },

    viewListing: function(listing_id) {
        this.featuredListingId = listing_id;    // Sent along with fetch() in this.explore()
        this.explore();
    }
});

App = new AppRouter();

// Enable pushState for compatible browsers
var enablePushState = true;  

// Disable for older browsers (IE8, IE9 etc)
var pushState = !!(enablePushState && window.history && window.history.pushState);

if(pushState) {
    Backbone.history.start({
        pushState: true,
        root: '/'
    })
} else {
    Backbone.history.start({
        pushState: false,
        root: '/'
    })
}
```

**Problem:** As you can see in the above code, I tried to disable pushstates with  `pushState: false` if it is an incompatible browser.

However for IE to access what would normally work for a normal browser (`http://mydomain.com/explore`), IE will need to go to `http://mydomain.com/explore/#explore` which is making things confusing! Further more to access `http://mydomain.com/explore/1234` IE needs to go to `http://mydomain.com/explore/#explore/1234`

How should this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want `http://mydomain.com/explore/#explore` url, then you have to redirect to 
`http://mydomain.com/#explore` so Backbone will start with it instead.

```
if(!pushState && window.location.pathname != "/") {
  window.location.replace("/#" + window.location.pathname)
}
```

UPD: you'll probably have to remove the leading slash when setting path as a hash `window.location.pathname.substr(1)`

UPD2: if you want `/explore/` to be the root for your backbone routes then you have to exclude it from routes and set as a root in `History.start({root: "/explore/"})`

```
routes: {
    '': 'explore',
    ':id': 'viewListing',
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it redirects (as expected) from `http://mydomain.com/explore` to `http://mydomain.com/#/explore`. However `http://mydomain.com` is the welcome/splash page and not the app page (`http://mydomain.com/explore`)

Comment: Then you probably have to remove `/explore/` from your Backbone routes, set it as a root in `Backbone.history.start({root: '/explore/'})`.