# Backbone form submit routing

Tags: javascript, forms, backbone.js

Is it possible to have a Router implementation similar to the following?

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '' : 'search',
        '*querystring' : 'results'
    },
    search: function() {
        // load search view
    },
    results: function(querystring) {
        // load search view
        // make ajax request using querystring
    }
});
```

The search view has a form that when submitted should go to the results view which will parse the url for the query, submit an ajax request and then display the response.

Obviously something like this would make more sense

```
'results?*querystring' : 'results'
```

But I can't get my form to submit the URL in that format.

When put my form action as `<form action="index.html/results">` I get  `http://localhost:8000/index.html/results?c=foo&a=bar` as my URL.

This is close, but I really need `http://localhost:8000/index.html#/results?c=foo&a=bar` and when I try to do this with `<form action="index.html#/results">` it gives me `http://localhost:8000/index.html?c=foo&a=bar#/results` which is not what I want :(

This is why I would rather just have no form action and instead have a route that can will parse the query if one exists.

Ok thanks for reading. Hopefully someone understands some of that and can help me out.

Comment: It seems your form is submitted and page is getting refreshed. Can you try preventing the form submitting ?

Answer (score 0):

don't put pushstate to true, set it to false

[Backbone.js PushStates: Fallback for Internet Explorer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253696/backbone-js-pushstates-fallback-for-internet-explorer-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove form or prevent the submission
2. Simply get the params and trigger a route
3. Handle the params appropriately in the triggered route.

**Router**

```
routes:{
  'search':'search'     //queryString is automatically passed as last param in backbone 1.1
},
search: function(queryString){
  //Write your logic to do the search
}
```

**View:**

```
events:{
'submit form':'preventAndNavigate'
},
preventAndNavigate: function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var query = $(e.currentTarget).serialize();
  Backbone.history.navigate('search?'+query,{trigger:true});
}
```

**Docs :**

Backbone Routers now handle query params in route fragments, passing them into the handler as the last argument. Routes specified as strings should no longer include the query string ('foo?:query' should be 'foo').

**References :**

http://backbonejs.org/#changelog